# Java : create DOS formatted text file

Tags: java

I have a tomcat running on a Linux server.
My webapp is creating text files that must be imported by another external system that accepts DOS/Windows formatted files.

```
FileWriterWithEncoding writer;  
writer = new FileWriterWithEncoding(file,"UTF-8", true);
PrintWriter printer = new PrintWriter(writer);
```

How can I create such DOS formatted files with Java on a Linux server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the line endings you write are "\r\n", this is the Windows way of writing them (*carriage return* character + *line feed* character) .

Comment: I am adding \r\n at the end of each line. Strange thing : on the first line I have this : INTRACOMF1KF1021       1109507612943000130468955606, If I replace INTRACOMF1KF1021 by INTRACOMF1KF1021 from a DOS formatted file, my file is well imported in the external system

Comment: Try to encode the file whith charset CP1252 (Windows default), or try a default DOS charset (see here : http://www.kostis.net/charsets/trans130/cpdos.htm )